# Swift 3 multiple gestureRecorgnizer SWRevealController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I have two gestureRecognizer I want to use.

1) Tap to close side menu (SWRevealController)

2) Tap view to dismiss keyboard

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    menuBtn.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginController.dismissKeyboard))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

Having both of these lines together, the dismiss keyboard gestureRecognizer trumps the revealViewController. How can I combine this this use both gestures together?

Comment: try with tags once

Comment: Can you post an answer with my code edited?

Answer (score 0):

Make condition in `LoginController.dismissKeyboard` method. 
check if `isKeyboard` is open, then close it. Otherwise close the (SWRevealController) sidemenu.

For check keyboard is open or not you can use post notification of `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` methods.